# Is there anything like IPython / IRB for Perl?

Tags: perl, shell

I've grown accustomed to using IPython to try things out whilst learning Python, and now I have to learn Perl for a new job.

Is there anything out there like IPython for Perl? In particular, I'm interested in completion and access to help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I usually just use `perl -de0`, but I've heard of:

- [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3A%3AREPL)
- [perlconsole](http://www.sukria.net/perlconsole.html)

Comment: I recommend Devel::REPL, really useful

Comment: ++ Devel::REPL, has a neat plugin system with lots of functionality.

Comment: A slightly more recent addition is tinyrepl (Eval::WithLexicals), which is a little bit smaller, and uses a crazy non-XS way to persist lexicals.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a less featurefull environment by using the debugger "stand-alone".

```
perl -de 42
```

(42 is just a constant in order to have a non null "script" loaded).

From there, you can `use My::Module` and so on.  I'm not sure there is a full irb-like program.

Comment: I was wandering what this 42 was, and whether it was specific for something, as it also shows in http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html ... So thanks for that note; also [Programming Perl: The Perl Debugger](http://books.google.com/books?id=THyeTrOEh7cC&pg=PA603&lpg=PA603) notes that it can be arbitrarily chosen... So `42` is likely chosen as it is the answer to life, universe and everyhing `:)` .. But I'm getting more used to `perl -d -e shell`; works the same ..  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATED FOR RECENT CHANGES]

IPython is no longer just Python; Jupyter can be used for any language with a [kernel](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages) implementation. Zakariyya Mughal released a [Perl kernel](https://metacpan.org/release/Devel-IPerl) last year, so I would recommend trying/contributing to that.

Comment: @JB Thanks. Checking this brought about a happy update!

Answer (score -6):

[From Perl FAQ](http://www.perl.com/doc/FAQs/FAQ/oldfaq-html/Q3.7.html):

> ### Perl FAQ 3.7
>
> ## Is there a perl shell?
>
> Not really. Perl is a programming language, not a command interpreter.

This was the reason why I swhitched from Perl to Python.
Anythow, several python [shell workarounds](http://www.google.co.il/search?q=%22perl+shell) do exist, but they are not even close to IPython

Comment: the IRB is not a shell, it is a REPL

Comment: There is [Zoidberg](http://p3rl.org/Zoidberg) however as Noah said, the OP is not asking for a shell but a REPL

Comment: This answer is not what the question ask for.  It's not even a perl-ished answer.